# How can I remove empty lists from within another list?

Tags: python, list, reddit, editing, python-re

After running text through this code:

```
import re


def text_manipulator(text):
    paras = re.split('\n|\n ', text)
    item_number = 0
    for item in paras:
        item_replace = re.split('(?<=[.!?]) +', item)
        paras[item_number] = item_replace
        item_number += 1
    fixed_paras = [x for x in paras if x]
    return fixed_paras
```

I'm left with this.

```
[["Not a postal worker, but I'm good friends with the one on my route,"], [''], ['He has helped me through some tough times (just a nice guy to talk to)'], [''], ['I often offer him a cold gallon of water or a energy drink, he seems to really enjoy.', 'He is a real down to earth guy.']]
```

What can I do differently to be left with this?:

```
[["Not a postal worker, but I'm good friends with the one on my route,"], ['He has helped me through some tough times (just a nice guy to talk to)'], ['I often offer him a cold gallon of water or a energy drink, he seems to really enjoy.', 'He is a real down to earth guy.']]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That list isn't empty. However, the item in it is empty. So `[x for x in paras if any(x)]` would work, and note, would also filter something like `['','']`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks very much that's worked a treat! Would you mind explaining how that code actually works? If you have the time ofc, cheers

Comment: [here are the relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for `any(iterable)`:

> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return `False`.

Hence when a list of Strings is passed to `Any` and if all of the elements in list are empty strings then it will return `False` as Empty String is equivalent to `False`.

So in your code replacing the second last line with:

```py
fixed_paras = [x for x in paras if any(x)]
```

will eliminate the lists with empty strings too.

**Note:** This answer is based on [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s comment